# Обособление оборота с «например»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

*Мы умышленно оставляем в стороне вопрос: стал ли он результатом эволюции животных либо появился на свет в результате воздействия иных, например **космических** сил.*

Как я понимаю, словосочетание "например космических" — это пояснительный оборот (за терминологию не ручаюсь) к слову "сил", но в таком случае, как мне кажется, оборот должен обособляться.

С другой стороны, оборотом может быть все словосочетание "например космических сил", и в таком случае вроде все правильно, но как-то нелогично, ведь слово, которое он поясняет, отсутствует. Или это что-то вроде эллипсиса?

Вопрос: правильно ли сделано, что после слова "космических" пропущена запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагается блиц-ответ (пока без ссылок).

*Мы умышленно оставляем в стороне вопрос: стал ли он результатом эволюции животных либо появился на свет в результате воздействия **иных, например космических, сил.***

Пояснение

1. Уберем "например":

*...в результате воздействия **иных, космических** сил.*

По Розенталю это пояснительные определения, но они пишутся через запятую (как однородные).

2. А если так:

*...в результате воздействия иных, **космических**, сил.*

Теоретически обособление определения возможно, но практически для одиночных определений не применяется. А вот оборот в такой позиции можно обособить.

3. Решение:

*...в результате воздействия **иных, например космических, сил**.*

Как известно (еще с 1956 года), вводное слово "например" может присоединяться к уточняющему слову в качестве союзного средства.

Answer (score 1):

Вы верно заметили, что если счесть *"например космических сил"* целым оборотом, то непонятно, кто такие *"иные"*. Эллипсисом это не выглядит. В таком варианте прилагательное *"иные"* скорее переходит в разряд существительных, то есть субстантивируется (как, например, Иные у Лукьяненко в "Дозорах"). Вряд ли вы это имели в виду, поэтому, на мой взгляд, несомненно правильная пунктуация: *...иных, например космических, сил.*